# Accessing anonymous array in javascript

Tags: javascript

How can we access an anonymous array in an object using javascript or jQuery?
We are receiving this object from some application which we cannot modify/access.

```
 obj = Object
    : Array[3]
       0: Object
       1: Object
       2: Object
```

We tried using `for...in loop` but that didn't work.[image]

Comment: What code you want? I want code to access this JSON object using javascript.

Comment: can you please show your json string?

Comment: Image for JSON string uploaded. Please check.

Comment: Image is not pretty clear , try changing into a normal json and add here.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an empty key.

```
var array = obj[''];
```

Note that `null` and `undefined` can be keys too.

```
var array = obj[null];
var array = obj[undefined];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would need to see more code, but I do understand that you can't access it.
If I had this problem, I would just start calling the JSON and reconstructing it in my own code. Perhaps not the most elegant solution, but it works.

Comment: Yes I could not find any solution to access that anonymous array. There is no other code, i am just getting this object from one component and i need to access the array now. Can you please help, as you told, how can start calling the JSON, i tried using JSON.parse, but it is giving error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it an array that you're trying to iterate

```
var arr = item.props.AlarmColumns;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    console.log(arr[i]);    
}
```

Comment: item.props.AlarmColumns is an object and not an Array. It has a anonymous member []. We tried using arr[i], but it returns undefined.